# std::pair used in std::map

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a problem with my program. I get an error when it reaches

```
cout << it->second << endl;
```

My program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    map<pair<int, int>, int> kwadraty;
    long long ile;
    cin >> ile;
    int temp1, temp2;
    for(int i = 0; i < ile; i++)
    {
        cin >> temp1 >> temp2;
        kwadraty[pair<int, int>(temp1, temp2)]++;
    }

    for(map<pair<int, int>, int>::iterator it; it != kwadraty.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << it->second << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone see where is a problem ?

Comment: I can see one problem: you haven't told us what the error is.

Comment: I recommend at least `std::make_pair` instead of `pair<int, int>(...)`, but since this is C++11, `kwadraty[{temp1, temp2}]` will do. In addition, instead of `map<pair<int, int>, int>::iterator`, just use `auto`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to initialise the iterator:

```
for(auto it = kwadraty.begin(); it != kwadraty.end(); it++)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```